# Matrix complicated equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 3 & 4\\
    3 & 6 & 9\\
    1 & 6 & 4
  \end{bmatrix},$$
$B$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix and $$A \cdot A^{T} \cdot A +3B^{-1} =0$$

What would be the value of 
$ \det( \operatorname{adj} (A^{-1}(B^{-1}){2B^{T}}))$ ?

Comment: Do you have some idea how you can start?

Comment: no, I tried to find $$B^{-1}$$ and then the $$B$$ from that. then just solved it... but it was so long and probably isn't the way... + I did mistakes in the middle for sure.
I will be glad to see full solution if possible

Comment: I am not sure if this is the only way to solve this, but you may find $B^{-1}$ from the given equation and then just compute the matrix whose determinant you need to find. This is really tedious, but it solves your problem nevertheless.

Comment: yea that's what I did but I got the wrong answer... you have so many places to mistake once and then all this question can't be solved

Comment: The question is not clear. We cannot take an arbitrary $B$. We should say that $B$ is given by $B=-3A^{-1}A^{-T}A^{-1}$

Comment: If you make mistakes then only way to get rid of mistakes is to practice more.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$X =  |( \operatorname{adj} (A^{-1}(B^{-1}){2B^{T}})|
 = |(\operatorname{adj}(2B^T) \operatorname{adj}(B^{-1})\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1}))| $$
$$ = |2B^T|^2 |B^{-1}|^2 |A^{-1}|^2 = 2^6 |B|^2 \cfrac{1}{(|A||B|)^2} = \cfrac{2^6}{|A|^2}$$

I hope now you can figure out $|A|$.

Comment: $$|A| = 9$$ which mean it's $$2^6/81$$ but that's not the answer :S

Comment: I really can't figure out where I did wrong?

Comment: Tell us what's the suggested answer, please.

Comment: @HelpMePlease We are right, See this https://imgur.com/a/SNcaFs6 A program to compute the same in python.

Answer (score 2):

$B$ is a red herring here and might be replaced by any invertible $3\times3$-matrix.

Since $\operatorname{adj}(C)=\det(C)C^{-1}$ for invertible $C$ we have
$$\det(\operatorname{adj}(C)=\det(C^{-1}\cdot\det(C))=(\det(C))^3\det(C^{-1})=(\det(C))^2$$
if $C$ is of type $3\times3$.

Now happily compute 
\begin{align}\det( \operatorname{adj} (A^{-1}B^{-1}{2B^{T}})
&=\bigl(\det(A^{-1}B^{-1}2B^{T})\bigr)^2\\
&=\bigl(2^3\cdot\det(A^{-1})
\underbrace{\det(B^{-1})\det(B^{T})}_{=1}\bigr)^2\\
&=\left(2^3\cdot\frac{1}{9}\right)^2
=\frac{64}{81}
\end{align}
as $\det(A)=9$.

Answer (score 1):

We can calculate $B^{-1}$, since
$$A \cdot A^{T} \cdot A +3B^{-1} =0 \leftrightarrow -3B^{-1} = A \cdot A^{T} \cdot A$$
So
$$\begin{align} -3B^{-1} &= \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 3 & 4\\
    3 & 6 & 9\\
    1 & 6 & 4
  \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 3 & 1\\
    3 & 6 & 6\\
    4 & 9 & 4
  \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 3 & 4\\
    3 & 6 & 9\\
    1 & 6 & 4
  \end{bmatrix} = \\ &=
\begin{bmatrix}
    26 & 57 & 35\\
    57 & 126 & 75\\
    35 & 75 & 53
  \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 3 & 4\\
    3 & 6 & 9\\
    1 & 6 & 4
  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    232 & 630 & 757\\
    510 & 1377 & 1662\\
    313 & 873 & 1027
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$
Dividing both sides by $-3$ we get
$$B^{-1} = \frac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix}
    -232 & -630 & -757\\
    -510 & -1377 & -1662\\
    -313 & -873 & -1027
  \end{bmatrix}$$
From this, we can calculate $B$, since $B = (B^{-1})^{-1}$. We just need to invert the above matrix.
$$B = \left(\frac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix}
    -232 & -630 & -757\\
    -510 & -1377 & -1662\\
    -313 & -873 & -1027
  \end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{9}\begin{bmatrix}
    1361 & -513 & -173\\
    132 & -49 & -18\\
    -527 & 198 & 68
  \end{bmatrix}$$
And from this we can easily calculate everything we need:
$$A^{-1}(B^{-1}){2B^{T}} = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 3 & 4\\
    3 & 6 & 9\\
    1 & 6 & 4
  \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \cdot \frac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix}
    -232 & -630 & -757\\
    -510 & -1377 & -1662\\
    -313 & -873 & -1027
  \end{bmatrix} \cdot 2 \cdot \frac{1}{9}\begin{bmatrix}
    1361 & -513 & -173\\
    132 & -49 & -18\\
    -527 & 198 & 68
  \end{bmatrix}^{T} = \\
= \frac{2}{27} \cdot \frac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix}
    -10 & 4 & 1\\
    -1 & 0 & 1\\
    4 & -1 & -1
  \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
    -232 & -630 & -757\\
    -510 & -1377 & -1662\\
    -313 & -873 & -1027
  \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
    1361 & 132 & -527\\
    -513 & -49 & 198\\
    -173 & -18 & 68
  \end{bmatrix} = \\ = -\frac{2}{81} \begin{bmatrix}
    33& 81 & 105\\
    81 & 243 & 270\\
    105 & 270 & 339
  \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
    1361 & 132 & -527\\
    -513 & -49 & 198\\
    -173 & -18 & 68
  \end{bmatrix} = \frac{2}{9} \begin{bmatrix}
    1645 & 167 & -643\\
    6792 & 675 & -2643\\
    6028 & 608 & -2353
  \end{bmatrix}.$$
And now for the $\operatorname{adj}$:
$$\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1}(B^{-1}){2B^{T}}) = \operatorname{adj}\frac{2}{9} \begin{bmatrix}
    1645 & 167 & -643\\
    6792 & 675 & -2643\\
    6028 & 608 & -2353
  \end{bmatrix} \stackrel{\text{adj is linear}}{=} \\ = \frac{2}{9} \cdot \operatorname{adj} \begin{bmatrix}
    1645 & 167 & -643\\
    6792 & 675 & -2643\\
    6028 & 608 & -2353\end{bmatrix} = \frac{2}{9} \begin{bmatrix}
    18669 & 2007 & -7356\\
    49572 & 5319 & -19521\\
    60636 & 6516 & -23889\end{bmatrix}$$
And finally:
$$\det( \operatorname{adj} (A^{-1}(B^{-1}){2B^{T}})) \stackrel{\text{det is linear}}{=} \frac{2}{9} \cdot \det \begin{bmatrix}
    18669 & 2007 & -7356\\
    49572 & 5319 & -19521\\
    60636 & 6516 & -23889\end{bmatrix} = \frac{2}{9} \cdot 6561 = 1458.$$

So the final answer is $1458$.

Comment: You are doing something wrong, See this https://imgur.com/a/SNcaFs6

Comment: @AjayMishra DId you also calculate the matrix adjugate?

Comment: I used $det(adj(A)) = det(A)^{n-1}$ where n is order of determinant

Comment: Check this, $Adj(c \mathbf A) \ne cAdj( \mathbf A)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Properties

Comment: Check this, $Det(c \mathbf A) \ne c Det( \mathbf A)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant

Comment: Your answer is off by the factor of $(2/9)^5$

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is invertible, it follows that $B = -3A^{-1}A^{-T}A^{-1}$ and therefore that

\begin{align}
\det( \operatorname{adj} (A^{-1}(B^{-1}){2B^{T}})) &=\det\left( \operatorname{adj} \left(A^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{3}A A^{T}  A \right){(-6A^{-T}A^{-1}A^{-T}})\right)\right). 
\end{align}

Since you already know $A$, this is just a computation.

Answer (score 0):

No need to find the value of matrix $B$ since
\begin{equation}
B^{-1}=-\frac{1}{3} A A^T A
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
B=-\frac{1}{3}(A A^T A)^{-1} = 3 A^{-1} A^{-T} A^{-1}
\end{equation}
put into the desired system
\begin{align}
A^{-1}(B^{-1})2B^T &=A^{-1} (-\frac{1}{3} A A^T A) 2 (3 A^{-1} A^{-T} A^{-1})
\notag \\
&= 2(A^{-1}A)A^T (A A^{-1}) A^{-T} A^{-1}
\notag \\
&= 2A^T  A^{-T} A^{-1}
\notag \\
&= 2A^{-1} 
\end{align}
where
\begin{equation}
A^{-1}=-\frac{1}{3}
\begin{pmatrix}-10 & 4 & 1\\ -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 4 & -1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
then find the result of $det(adj(A^{-1}))$.

Comment: I got 1/81 using this which isn't the correct answer sadly :(

Comment: what's the answer @HelpMePlease ? Are you sure you've typed the question correctly?

Comment: I don't know the answer the system is just telling me im put the wrong answer

Comment: Check the equation after "put the desired..", you have to substitute $2B^T$ not $2B$